# Writing a method to calculate length/average

Tags: java, class, methods

I am trying to write a class with all the methods I need for my main, but am having trouble figuring out how to ascertain the desired values using the methods.  The ones I am having trouble with are getAverageLength and getCount.

Current Output:

```
The length of Line 1 is 1.0
The length of Line 2 is 10.0
There are 0 lines and the average length is 0
The length of Line 1 is 1.0
The length of Line 2 is 10.0
The length of Line 3 is 7.0
There are 0 lines and the average length is 0
```

Expected Output:

```
The length of Line 1 is 1
The length of Line 2 is 10
There are 2 lines and the average length is 5.5
The length of Line 1 is 7
The length of Line 2 is 10
The length of Line 3 is 7
There are 3 lines and the average length is 8.0
```

This is the portion of my main method that I am using.

```
public class TestParts {

public static void main(String[] args) {

     MyLine ml1 = new MyLine();
     MyLine ml2 = new MyLine(10);
     System.out.println("The length of Line 1 is " + ml1.getLength());
     System.out.println("The length of Line 2 is " + ml2.getLength());
     System.out.println("There are " + MyLine.getCount() +
     " lines and the average length is " + MyLine.getAverageLength());
     MyLine ml3 = new MyLine(7);
     ml1.setLength(7);
     System.out.println("The length of Line 1 is " + ml1.getLength());
     System.out.println("The length of Line 2 is " + ml2.getLength());
     System.out.println("The length of Line 3 is " + ml3.getLength());
     System.out.println("There are " + MyLine.getCount() +
     " lines and the average length is " + MyLine.getAverageLength());
    }
}
```

And the following is the seperate class that I am writing to calculate the values.

```
class MyLine {
private double getLength;

MyLine() {
    getLength = 1;
}

double getLength() {
    return getLength;
}

MyLine(double setLength) {
    getLength = setLength;
}

public void setLength(int i) {
    getLength = getLength();
}

public static int getCount() {

    return 0;
}

public static int getAverageLength() {

    return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: What is your expected and actual output?

Comment: I just added the actual and expected to the question.

Comment: Your setLength method does nothing. In fact your class has so many problems I would scrap it and start again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `getCount`, make a `static int` that is incremented by each constructor.

For `getAverageLength`, make a `static int` with the sum of the lines that is added to by each constructor and divide it by the count.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't know how to do any of this.

Comment: In the class, make a `static int count` and a `static int sum`. Then, in each constructor, add `count++;` and `sum += getLength;` at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the code.
First, recommend documenting what the methods are supposed to do in comments.
This will help you and others.
Second, these methods:

```
public void setLength(int i) {
    getLength = getLength();
}
```

The `getLength` private member variable is probably badly named.
I suspect the intent was a noun like `length` whereas `getLength()` is a method intended to return the current `length`.
This method takes a primitive `int` datatype to set a type of `double`.
Was this intentional?
Looks like a misconception.
Moreover, it has no function as it just sets the `getLength` (again, should be `length`) variable to the return value of the method `getLength()`, which in turn returns the value of `getLength`. This is a remedial logic and basic math problem:
A = 1 = getLength() = A = 1

```
public static int getCount() {

    return 0;
}
```

Why would anything other than zero be expected to be returned from this method?

public static int getAverageLength() {

```
return 0;
```

}

Same here ... fundamental logic problem.

I would not post this kind of question on the forum as it lacks doing basic homework before posing the question.

Comment: The 0's were placeholders just to show the method, thought that was obvious.

Comment: The problem states actual versus expected outcomes: There are 0 lines and the average length is 0 ... versus expected: There are 2 lines and the average length is 5.5. If the values are explicitly set to zero, how could the expected outcome ever be anything other than zero?

Answer (score 0):

build a `HashMap<MyLine, Integer>`
Integer is the length of the MyLine.

you just put those `MyLine` objects you want to count into that map.

`{ml1:0,
ml2:10,
ml3:7}`

then you could calculate everything you want.